# Weird RNP samba devices in Workgroup

Tags: security, samba, netbios

in the Network folder of all Windows computers and in the output of smbtree command I see a lot of devices with strange names (legitimate names obfuscated with #).

```
WORKGROUP
        \\WEBSERVER      
        \\RNPA82FE9      
        \\RNP002673AB3150
        \\RNP002673AB3141
        \\RNP002673AB313C
        \\RNP002673AB310B
        \\RNP002673AB3103
        \\RNP002673AB30DD
        \\RNP002673AB2F7A
        \\RNP002673AB2F4B
        \\RNP002673AB2E86
        \\RNP002673AB2DFD
        \\RNP002673AB2DFB
        \\RNP002673A85831
        \\RNP002673A857D0
        \\PC-######
        \\#######-PC
        \\FR######        
        \\DESKTOP-#####
        \\BRN008077576ADE
        \\BRN008077510CFD
```

We are in a 192.168.0.X network and arp-scan, nmap, nbtscan, and even nmblookup failed to find anything related to these names:

```
name_query failed to find name RNPA82FE9
name_query failed to find name RNP002673AB3150
name_query failed to find name RNP002673AB3141
name_query failed to find name RNP002673AB313C
```

This is a very simple network, there are:

- 7 PC (some linux and some windows, some in wireless and some wired)
- some Android phones
- a couple of iPhones
- one or two printers
- 6-7 voip Snom phones
- a Cisco access point

The network is connected to a virtual machine with Endian Firewall that acts as firewall towards internet and as router for another network with a domain controller and a file server. The domain name on the domain controller is not WORKGROUP.

Any idea? Where does this information is read from?

Obviously I double cheched but the RNP* strings are not the name of anything in the network and the numbers are not related to any mac address (even if they *seem* mac addresses).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are your printers Ricoh printers?

Comment: No, there are no Ricoh printers. They are a both Samsung.